# Rails 3 doesn't have `rake gems:unpack`, what to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

It seems rails 3 doesn't have `rake gems:unpack`, what we should use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is bundler now with rails 3.  The equivalent is

```
> bundle package
```

More on bundler at: http://gembundler.com/